# ViewPager inside RecylerView, click not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, click

My RecyclerView's item layout has a ViewPager on top and some views below it. ViewPager works fine, swipes good. But the recycler item click is not working on clicking the ViewPager (I've set click on the entire item). But if I click the content below the ViewPager, Click works.

here's the RecyclerView's list item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              xmlns:attrs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,4:2"/>

            <com.rd.PageIndicatorView
                    android:id="@+id/pageIndicatorView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    app:piv_animationType="scale"
                    app:piv_dynamicCount="true"
                    app:piv_interactiveAnimation="true"
                    app:piv_selectedColor="@color/whiteSmoke"
                    app:piv_unselectedColor="@color/white25Transparent"
                    app:piv_viewPager="@id/viewPager"
                    attrs:piv_padding="2dp"
                    attrs:piv_radius="4dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/viewpager" android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>

            <com.codeairs.wattamatte.customcontrols.textview.MPRegularTextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/viewpager" android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="12dp" android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp" android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                    android:text="Cosy Duplex - 42m2" android:textColor="@color/stPatricksBlue"/>

            <com.codeairs.wattamatte.customcontrols.textview.MPMediumTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/RoomDimensTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/name" android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/name"
                    android:text="3p"/>

            <com.codeairs.wattamatte.customcontrols.textview.MPMediumTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/RoomDimensTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/name" android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv1"
                    android:layout_marginStart="12dp" android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:text="2ch"/>

            <com.codeairs.wattamatte.customcontrols.textview.MPMediumTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/RoomDimensTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/name" android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv2"
                    android:layout_marginStart="12dp" android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:text="4m"/>

            <com.codeairs.wattamatte.customcontrols.textview.MPRegularTextView
                    android:id="@+id/location"
                    android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv1" android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv1" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    android:text="Villeurbanne" android:textColor="@color/darkSlateBlue"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

            <com.codeairs.wattamatte.customcontrols.textview.MPBoldTextView
                    android:id="@+id/price"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                    android:text="450€ C.C" android:textColor="@color/stPatricksBlue" android:textSize="17sp"/>

            <View
                    android:id="@+id/toggleBG"
                    android:layout_width="36dp" android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/solid_white_circle"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/viewpager"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/viewpager"/>

            <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/favoritesToggleButton"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_fav_toggle"
                    android:textOn=""
                    android:textOff=""
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/toggleBG"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/toggleBG"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/toggleBG"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/toggleBG"/>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

RecylerView Adapter

```
public class RoomsListRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoomsListRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<Room> mValues;
    private final List<String> favRoomsIds;
    private final OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private final Context mContext;

    public RoomsListRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Room> items, List<String> favRoomsIds,
                                        OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener, Context mContext) {
        mValues = items;
        mListener = listener;
        this.favRoomsIds = favRoomsIds;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_rooms_list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);

        holder.imgPager.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(mContext, holder.mItem.property.pictures));
        holder.pageIndicatorView.setCount(holder.mItem.property.pictures.size());
        holder.pageIndicatorView.setSelection(0);
        holder.imgPager.addOnPageChangeListener(getPageChangeListener(holder));

        holder.name.setText(holder.mItem.property.name);
        holder.location.setText(holder.mItem.property.address.city);
        holder.price.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0} € C.C", holder.mItem.property.price));

        holder.tv1.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0}p", holder.mItem.property.personCount));
        holder.tv2.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0}ch", holder.mItem.property.pieces));
        holder.tv3.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0}m²", holder.mItem.property.surface));

        holder.favToggle.setChecked(favRoomsIds.contains(holder.mItem.property.id));
        holder.favToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) ->
                toggleFavorite(holder.mItem.property.id, isChecked));

        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (null != mListener) {
                mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder.mItem, favRoomsIds.contains(holder.mItem.property.id));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        final View mView;
        Room mItem;
        ViewPager imgPager;
        TextView name, location, price, tv1, tv2, tv3;
        ToggleButton favToggle;
        PageIndicatorView pageIndicatorView;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            imgPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            location = view.findViewById(R.id.location);
            price = view.findViewById(R.id.price);
            tv1 = view.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            tv2 = view.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
            tv3 = view.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
            favToggle = view.findViewById(R.id.favoritesToggleButton);
            pageIndicatorView = view.findViewById(R.id.pageIndicatorView);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + " '" + "'";
        }
    }

    private void toggleFavorite(String propertyId, boolean fav) {
        if (fav)
            favRoomsIds.add(propertyId);
        else
            favRoomsIds.remove(propertyId);

        JsonObjectRequest request = NetworkUtils.toggleRoomFavoritesRequest(
                mContext, propertyId, fav, this::handleResponse, this::handleError);

        VolleySingleton.getInstance(mContext).addToRequestQueue(request);
    }

    private void handleResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Log.d("RoomFav.Response", response.toString());
    }

    private void handleError(VolleyError error) {

    }

    public void clear() {
        mValues.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addItems(List<Room> rooms) {
        mValues.addAll(rooms);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener getPageChangeListener(ViewHolder holder) {
        return new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                holder.pageIndicatorView.setSelected(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        };
    }
}
```

pager adapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> mItems;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<String> items) {
        mContext = context;
        mItems = items;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_image, collection, false);

        String url = mItems.get(position);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(url))
            Picasso.get().load(ApiPaths.IMG_PATH_PREFIX + url).into(img);

        collection.addView(img);
        return img;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup collection, int position, @NonNull Object view) {
        collection.removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

}
```

pager item

```
<ImageView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:clickable="false"/>
```

Comment: `itemView` is always root of the `viewholder`, in that case it's your `LinearLayout` from the XML. Even if you add clickListener to it, it will never receive it because it's below `ViewPager` which consumes all touch events.

Comment: So what do I do? I tried setting ClickListener on the ViewPager as well. But not working.

Comment: You can try adding click listeners inside each viewpager page, otherwise subclass ViewPager and write custom touchEvent that handles user taps as clicks in addition to default implementation.

Comment: yes, added ClickListener to each page and it works. Thank you